# Необходимо увеличить память в динамическом массиве

Tags: c++

Имею массив, например размером в 10 элементов. Необходимо увеличить массив на 1, добавив элемент. Прочитал на форуме, что необходимо создать новый массив с увеличенным объемом памяти, туда переписать старые элементы и вписать новый. Будет ли эти операции по скорости аналогичны, что и имеющийся `vector`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если *разово* - практически нет (вернее, зависит от того, в каком состоянии вектор в момент добавления).

Если много - вектор будет быстрее, потому что он не выделяет память для каждого элемента, а делает это сразу большими кусками - например, удваивая ее (и резервируя место для последующих добавлений).

Answer (score 1):

могут быть различия в скорости(из-за того что вектор увеличивается примерно в полтора раза), но принцип будет тот же, в любом случае создаётся новый массив, с увеличенным размеров и значение ссылки меняется на значение ссылки(указателя) на новый массив